# Kubernetes in company network without internet connection

Tags: kubernetes

I would like to install Kubernetes on CentOs VMs. These VMs are not connected to the internet, so it would be great to download binaries or RPM packages from somewhere and copy them to these machines, then do the installation.

For (Docker) images, I would like to access a company internal repository.

Since this is just for experimentation, I do not need production ready security.

Can someone give me advice on this? I am not an experienced sysadmin and would like to avoid to do everything completely "by hand". My hope is that there something like minikube that can be configured to work without internet connection.

Comment: Well, what have you already tried and what outcome is it producing for you? This is not a consultancy, it's for helping you solve problems. Separately, if you're "not an experienced sysadmin," then booting up an airgapped kubernetes install is not a good place to start. Have you already gotten a non-airgapped install to work in order to understand what the moving parts are?

Comment: @mdaniel I apologize if this is too general. It tried reading through documentations to find something helpful, but haven't. I understand that this might be not the easiest place to start, but building something outside the company network (so with internet access) means that I cannot put any real software (from us) into the cluster. But maybe you are right and should do more experimentation before I come back here.

Comment: As a first move, familiarizing yourself with deployment stacks (kubespray, kops, openshift, ...), in a connected scenario, is indeed a prerequisite here. Figuring out which tools fits your use case, and how they would integrate with corporate proxies, or how to disconnect them, would be easier given you already have some experience with your stack. For those latter steps, tools such as katello can help caching packages. squid for proxying when necessary, and a docker-registry container could help mirroring images, or products such as artifactory, kraken, ...